# Логирование в GWT

Tags: java, gwt

Как настроить Логгирование на клиентской стороне в GWT?

Comment: На англоязычном stackoverflow есть хороший ответ. [Ссылка на вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247424/how-to-print-to-the-console-in-gwt)

Comment: @kandellak и куда выводятся сообщения этим способом? В консоль браузера?

Comment: если указать <inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging" /> в вашмодуль.gwt.xml и логировать вот так logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Сообщение"); то будет видно в консоли браузера

Comment: @kandellak А если мы говорим о выводе в файл? Как достичь эффекта такого? Log4j не работает.

Comment: "Логирование на клиентской стороне" в вашем вопросе для меня означает логирование в браузере.

Comment: а логировать в файл на стороне клиента возможно ли?

Comment: @kandellak. Понял, сказал глупость, сервисную часть по такому же принципу Логировать?